# No module named 'flask' when deploying a Python Flask app to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I followed the tutorial and deployed Google's sample Hello World app without any errors.

But when I tried to deploy my own Flask app, I got a 502 error.

Google Cloud debug terminal returns:

```
File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>
  from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/static' , methods = ['GET','POST'])

def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the Python 2 runtime or the Python 3 runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Second Generation Python 3 runtime, you need to add `flask` to a file named `requirements.txt` (see "[Specifying Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)").

If you're using the First Generation Python 2 runtime, you need to vendor it along side your application (see "[Using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)").

Comment: I had, I follow exactly what the tutorial and deploy the Hello world without any error. I only change their main.py with my code. All set, all command for the terminal are matched, yet it still cannot found module Flask

Comment: you have to name all directory correctly, forget an "s" in requirements.txt prevent app engine to read this file.